# Title tag change in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

```
<title>Laravel</title>
```

I use following

```
/ In app.js
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'

Vue.use(VueMeta)

// in vue file

<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  metaInfo: { title: 'Dashboard' },
};
</script>
```

It's change document title, not actual title tag (Source Code).
i want to change title also in source-code.(Ctrl+U);

Comment: "view source" shows the source of the page when first loaded. Changes done via JavaScript will not be reflected. Usually this is resolved when using server-side rendering ([SSR](https://ssr.vuejs.org/)) but I have never managed to get this to work with Laravel. However you may have better luck. There's a nice tutorial [here](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/06/vue-js-laravel-server-side-rendering/) as well if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`document.title = 'Dashboard'`

Comment: It's change document title, not actual title tag (Source Code).